# Convert a List Partially JSON Formatted Data into a Map

Tags: java, json, arraylist, hashmap

I have a following Object Data as below

```
[{
name = john , id=1,email id  : [abc@gmail.com,def@gmail.com,ghi@gmail.com]
},{
name = joy, id=2,email id  : [jkl@gmail.com,mno@gmail.com,pqr@gmail.com]
}]
```

I want the following to be converted to Map 
as

```
{john=[abc@gmail.com,def@gmail.com,ghi@gmail.com]},{joy= [jkl@gmail.com,mno@gmail.com,pqr@gmail.com]}
```

in Java how will I be able to achieve this.

Kindly help me with this

Comment: sadly as the data are shown as above, there is no easy way of doing this except actually parsing string yourself.

Comment: That json is wrong. Could you paste a correct one

Comment: @kimy82 Hi Buddy, Its similar to json but the requirement is what I have asked, I have a data as above, and want it as a MAP

Comment: Okei, it is weird to have something not following any correct data structure. I guess it is a plain string then?

Comment: @JohnHumanyun Just to confirm I understand, you literally have a string that matches what you show at the beginning of your question and you want to parse that string in Java. Is that correct?

Comment: @bhspencer Exactly

Comment: I would strongly push back on whoever gave your this task and try to get the producer of the data to produce valid JSON rather than a new broken serialization. Mixing = and colons, allowing spaces in property names without quoting the names. What a mess. Presumably there is no specification for this new format they are using. You could write something but it will be brittle and a pain to maintain. Sometimes the correct solution is not code but push back.

Comment: got you @bhspencer  Thanks much for the kind info

Comment: @bhspencer ... just a question, that is it possible to convert it to propert JSON format and then Extract them to the required format

Comment: Convert your one example string, sure that is possible. But what is the specification for this new input format. What other delightful surprises can we expect?

Answer (score 0):

no easy way of doing this, so much hard manual work with so many possibilities for errors, you can use this. as long as your data is EXACTLY as shown then this should work.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;




public class Person {




    int id;
    String name;
    List<String> emails;




    public static Person parse(String s) throws Exception {

        Person person = new Person();
        person.name = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(",")).replaceAll(".+= ?", "");
        s = s.substring(s.indexOf(",") + 1, s.length());
        person.id = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(",")).replaceAll(".+= ?", "").trim());
        s = s.substring(s.indexOf(",") + 1, s.length());
        s = s.replaceAll(".+: ?", "").replaceAll("[ \\[\\]]", "");
        person.emails = Arrays.asList(s.split(","));

        return person;

    }




    public static List<Person> parseMany(String s) throws Exception {

        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

        while (true){
            int openBracket = s.indexOf("{");
            int closeBracket = s.indexOf("}");

            if(closeBracket == -1){
                break;
            }
            people.add(parse(s.substring(openBracket, closeBracket)));
            s = s.substring(closeBracket + 1, s.length());

        }

        return people;

    }




    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String s = "[{name = john , id=1,email id  : [abc@gmail.com,def@gmail.com,ghi@gmail.com]},{name = joy, id=2,email id  : [jkl@gmail.com,mno@gmail.com,pqr@gmail.com]}]";

        List<Person> people = parseMany(s);

        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        for(Person person : people){
            map.put(person.name, person.emails);
        }

        System.out.println(map);

    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> {joy=[jkl@gmail.com, mno@gmail.com, pqr@gmail.com], john
>   =[abc@gmail.com, def@gmail.com, ghi@gmail.com]}

**NOTE:**

I didn't bother to comment this code, because problem doesn't follow any standard procedures.